# comparing two strings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, string-comparison

Is there any way to compare two strings in SQL Server 2008 stored procedure like below?

```
int returnval = STRCMP(str1, str2)
```

- returns 0 if the strings are the same
- returns -1 if the first argument is smaller than the second according to the current sort order.
- returns 1 otherwise.

Above method I find in the MySQL but not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is no built-in string compare function in SQL Server, you have to do it manually:

```
CASE
    WHEN str1 = str2 THEN 0
    WHEN str1 < str2 THEN -1
    WHEN str1 > str2 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL -- one of the strings is NULL so won't compare
END
```

Notes:

- you can wrap this via a UDF using `CREATE FUNCTION` etc.
- you may need NULL handling in case one of the compared strings is NULL
- `str1` and `str2` will be column names or @variables

Comment: You will use the case statement or User defined function to compare the string in sql server. You can check SOUNDEX & DIFFERENCE string function for more information regarding string comparability.

Comment: @Yogesh Bhadauirya: To clarify, SOUNDEX & DIFFERENCE don't compare alphabetically

Comment: You are right @gbn, but this is useful if OP knows something about string comparisons function which is useful to find  similarity of two strings.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
SELECT IIF(str1 = str2, 0, -1)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Your solution does not return 1 (one) when `str1` is larger than `str2` (according to the current sort order). Still, as per my understanding of how this website works, incorrect answers are still considered to be valid answers.