# How to compare two arabic string in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two strings:

```
a = 'على';
b = 'علي';
```

or

```
a = 'محمد';
b ='محــــــــــمد';
```

or

```
a= 'بُنْ'
b='بن'
```

```
a= 'يسرا'
b='يسرى'
```

and I already have data in database

What I have tried so far:

How can I compare them and return true?
i cant collect all cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing two strings in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623802/comparing-two-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: You haven''t explained what happened when you ran the query. I suppose you got an error, because `STRCMP` doesn't exist in the Oracle DBMS? Where do you get the values from?

Comment: yes, STRCMP doesn't exist in the Oracle DBMS and get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UTL_MATCH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_match.htm#ARPLS352), specifically the sub-program [UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_match.htm#CHDEFJFC)

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('على', 'علي') > 75 
    THEN 'Match' ELSE 'No Match' END as "Match Status" 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: when use it return different but two this name match                                                                               


SELECT CASE 
    WHEN UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('محمد', 'محمــد') > 75 
    THEN 'Match' ELSE 'No Match' END as "Match Status" 
FROM dual;

Comment: You can adjust the value of "sameness" by increasing or decreasing the `75`. It is basically a percentage of sameness.

Comment: I use it but I when i write with formatting Arabic word the result not true.  replace Formation in the Arabic language with empty in pl sql. I try 
  select   TRANSLATE('عــــــلًــــــي', 'ُ', '') from dual;   but return null.

Comment: @Emanmohamed Is your database setup to use an Arabic character set, or is it using a Western European char set (WE8ISO8859P1)? You can find out what you are currently using with the following statement: `select * from database_properties where PROPERTY_NAME in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');` If you are not using an Arabic char set (AR8ISO8859P6), you will run into difficulties using a lot of these string/word/phrase comparison functions/techniques. To change your char set, look into: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm#g1011430

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM DUAL
WHERE a = b;
```

A row will be returned if they are equal, no rows if not equal.

Comment: when compare a and b will find a not equal b   but a = 'يسرا ' and b= 'يسري '  are the same but different syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the comparision operator `=` or Oracle's SQL function `DECODE` in order to compare values.

```
select case when 'على' = 'علي' then 'same' else 'different' end from dual;

select decode('على' ,'علي', 'same', 'different') from dual;
```